# Use of powershell with sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I was wandering what were the possibility of interaction between powershell and sharepoint. Almost all our documentation at work is on sharepoint and was wandering if I could access the metadata associate to a file with powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is great tool for the SharePoint Administrator but not for the End User.

You can not run the powershell from client's machine. You need the Farm Admin rights to Run the PowerShell and get the data.

here are few blogs for more info:

[Use SharePoint 2010 PowerShell Cmdlets to Get and Manage Sites](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/21/use-sharepoint-2010-powershell-cmdlets-to-get-and-manage-sites.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010 PowerShell Cheat Sheet](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/sharepoint-2010-powershell-cheat-sheet/)

[Powershell for sharePoint 2010 Tutorial](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/11/18/powershell-for-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/)

Comment: I do have admin access so I guess I could get the metadata as you say. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, you can access the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manage SharePoint 2010/2013 with PowerShell. And yes, you can access SharePoint metadata via PowerShell.